# PHP multiplication float fail

Tags: php, floating-point, multiplication

I have a big trouble with the multiplication of floats.

here is the example:

> 750 * 10.7  = 8025

but in PHP the result is: 8024

why?

EDIT ------------

> 750 * 10.7 = 8024  (the real is 8025) 
>   750 * 10.2 = 7649  (the real is 7650)

but with 10.1 .. 10.9 works fine.
for while, I continue my reading...

Comment: I just did it in `PHP 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.4` and got 8025

Comment: <?php
    $outcome=750*10.7;
    echo $outcome;
    ?>

Gives me 8025.

Comment: because `0.1 / 2` is not equal to `0.05` in most of programming languages

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats normal due to float imprecision - floating-point numbers are imprecise, if you need to compute with precise numbers, use integers and emulate fractional parts on N places.

I recommend reading - [Wikipedia - Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Machine_precision)

Comment: if you need precise numbers you can use `bc_mul` or ext/gmp.